# Finding the index of a specific value in a cell in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, indexing, find, cell

I have a two dimensional cell where every element is either a) empty or b) a vector of varying length with values ranging from 0 to 2. I would like to get the indices of the cell elements where a certain value occurs or even better, the "complete" index of every occurrence of a certain value.

I'm currently working on an agent based model of disease spreading and this is done in order to find the positions of infected agents.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5):

Here's how I would do it:

```
% some example data
A = { [],     [], [3 4 5]
      [4 8 ], [], [0 2 3 0 1] };

p = 4; % value of interest

% Finding the indices:
% -------------------------

% use cellfun to find indices
I = cellfun(@(x) find(x==p), A, 'UniformOutput', false);

% check again for empties
% (just for consistency; you may skip this step)
I(cellfun('isempty', I)) = {[]};
```

Call this method1.

A loop is also possible:

```
I = cell(size(A));
for ii = 1:numel(I)
    I{ii} = find(A{ii} == p);
end
I(cellfun('isempty',I)) = {[]};
```

Call this method2.

Comparing the two methods for speed like so:

```
tic; for ii = 1:1e3, [method1], end; toc
tic; for ii = 1:1e3, [method2], end; toc
```

gives

```
Elapsed time is 0.483969 seconds.  % method1
Elapsed time is 0.047126 seconds.  % method2
```

on Matlab R2010b/32bit w/ Intel Core i3-2310M@2.10GHz w/ Ubuntu 11.10/2.6.38-13. This is mostly due to JIT on loops (and how terribly `cellfun` and anonymous functions seem to be implemented, mumblemumble..)

Anyway, in short, use the loop: it's better readable, and an order of magnitude faster than the vectorized solution.

Comment: Great answer; as JIT improves I think we will see less use for `cellfun` and equivalents. It can be very irritating now to have to try out a couple of different methods in order to see which way is quickest.